# Batch to list folders that don't contain a specific file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there a way to save in a text file all the folders (full path) that don't contain a file named "test", for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work

```
@echo off
for /d /r %%f in (*) do (
if not exist %%f\test.txt (
echo %%f >>C:\folders.txt
)
)
```

That will output all folders that don't contain the file `test.txt` to the file `C:\folders.txt`, just tweak/adjust to your needs.

Comment: thanks, but can I adjust it to match even the files that contain the name test in it?

Comment: You mean it would match a file called `hellotestRoxana.txt`?

Comment: Then use `%%f\*test*.*` to match any file with any extension that contains the word `test` in it at any point.